# Self Referencing Typescript Class

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, self-reference

I have a JSON object that i would like to represent in an angular2 typescript class. The JSON object has in it an array of objects of it's own type. The JSON object looks like this:

```
{ 
  "data": {
     "id": 5
     "type": "taxons",
     "attributes": {
       name: "Vehicles & Vehicle Accessories",
       "taxons": [{
         "id": 8,
         "type": "taxons",
         "attributes": {
            name: "Make",
            "taxons": []
         },
         "id": 9,
         "type": "taxons",
         "attributes": {
            name: "Model",
           "taxons": []
         }
        }]
  }
}
```

When I create the `taxon` model in typescript, I'm getting stuck on how to represent the self referencing `taxon` in the `taxons` array. 
I currently have the class like this.

```
export class Taxon {
  constructor (
    public id: number,
    public name: string,
    public taxons: //I am stuck here.
    )
}
```

How do I get reference to the `self` so that i can have something like

```
public taxons: Array<self>
```

Or how else can I do this to get the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use a class if you really need to.
All you have to do is specify the type.

```js
export class Taxon {
  constructor (
    public id: number,
    public name: string,
    public taxons: Taxon[]
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest doing this via an interface like so:

```
interface IFoo {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    foos?: IFoo[];
}

var foo: IFoo = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'name 1',
    foos: [
        {id: 2, name: 'child 2'}
    ]
}
```

The key is to make the `foos` property optional by using the `?`